# What is the best pratice of Using ContentProvider+Room to access Database in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development(java), recently i'm trying to apply ContentProvider to my project.

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverter), in Room, Entity class can have non-primitive data type attribute as long as you provide a proper TypeConvter. And I do so:

Here is my Entity class:

```
@Entity(
        indices = {
        @Index(value = {"w_pid"},unique = false),
        @Index(value = {"w_task_id"}, unique = false)
        },
        tableName = "WaterQualityData"
)
public class WaterQualityData {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "wid")
    public int wid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "w_task_id")
    public int w_task_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "w_pid")
    public int w_pid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "water_quality_data")
    public String water_quality_data;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "sampling_time")
    @TypeConverters(TimeConverters.class)
    public LocalDateTime sampling_time;
}
```

Here is my TypeConvter class:

```
public class TimeConverters {
    private static final ZoneId systemDefaultZoneID = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    private static final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:SSS";

    @TypeConverter
    public static String convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDate){
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_PATTERN);
        return locDate.format(fmt);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(String sqlDate){
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_PATTERN);
        return LocalDateTime.parse(sqlDate, fmt);
    }
}
```

The TimeConverters class works well in testing. However, when I want to insert a WaterQualityData Object into the Database through ContentResolver(ContentProvider has been properly implemented), I find that I must convert WaterQualityData Object to a ContentValues Object because the insert() method only accept ContentValues as parameter:

```
public @Nullable Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues values,@Nullable Bundle extras)
```

Then I try to carry out the converting, only to find that ContentValues do not accept non-primitive data type as its entry value (the `putObject(String key, Object o) method` is hided in the android source code):

```
    /** {@hide} */
    public void putObject(@Nullable String key, @Nullable Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            putNull(key);
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            put(key, (String) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Byte) {
            put(key, (Byte) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Short) {
            put(key, (Short) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
            put(key, (Integer) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Long) {
            put(key, (Long) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Float) {
            put(key, (Float) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            put(key, (Double) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            put(key, (Boolean) value);
        } else if (value instanceof byte[]) {
            put(key, (byte[]) value);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type " + value.getClass());
        }
    }
```

And it can be seen that even you call this method through reflection, non-primitive data type is not allowed except Wrapper object.
So if I want to insert the information of a WaterQualityData object into the database throuth ContentResolver, I need to do these:

1. convert each field of WaterQualityData into primitive data type and put them into a ContentValues object.
2. call `getContentResolver().insert(...)`
3. in my Dao, write a method using `@Query` annotation to insert information form ContentValues.

but if I do not use ContentProvider and directly access the Database object, I can happily do this since I use @TypeConverters annoation:

```
WaterQualityData waterQualityData = MyContentProviders.createWaterQualityData(...);
waterQualityDataDao = appDatabase.waterQualityDataDao();
waterQualityDataDao.insertAll(waterQualityData)
```

I think the latter is much more pleasant. The @TypeConverters annoation is not used in the former and **it is really annoying when you have to keep writing similar code that convert Entity object to Contentvalues object**.I am tired of writing method like this:

```
public static ContentValues WaterQualityDataToContentValues(WaterQualityData w){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(EnitiesUtil.WaterQualityData_TASK_ID, w.w_task_id);
    contentValues.put(EnitiesUtil.WaterQualityData_PARAMETER_ID, w.w_pid);
    contentValues.put(EnitiesUtil.WaterQualityData_DATA,w.water_quality_data);
    contentValues.put(EnitiesUtil.WaterQualityData_SAMPLING_TIMNE, w.sampling_time);
    return contentValues;
}
```

Is there a better way of using ContentProvider+Room to access Database in Android?